# Adding an asterisk via custom CSS is giving a 403 error

Tags: webforms

Using Drupal 8 and the Webform module, I am trying to add an asterisk to a required field label using the Custom CSS option in Webform by using this CSS style.

```
.form-required:after {
content: " *";
}
```

After adding the CSS style and trying to save the form, I get the following error message.

> 403 error - Access to this resource on the server is denied!

I can add any other character in the CSS. Why?

As work-around, I am adding the CSS style to the style.css file, but I would like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: I was able to inject your custom CSS via /admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/settings/assets without any problems. Are you able to reproduce this issue using https://simplytest.me?

Comment: Can you add this rule only? Maybe the while CSS has an issue

Comment: Try typing it as unicode (that's what CSS supports), for asterisks its: `content: " \002a";`. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a/index.htm Maybe it has to do with how server MIME types are served, or how Webform handles its custom CSS.